Karate MongoDB - Failed looking up TXT record for host cluster-name.xxx.mongodb.net
Using MongoDB Java driver v5.1, I can connect to the MongoDB cluster and query a document successfully from a Java main method. However, querying a document from MongoDB for Karate test gives the error: Failed looking up TXT record for host cluster-name.xxx.mongodb.net. My connection string is in the format: mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster-name.xxx.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority.
What is the correct way to connect to MongoDB from Karate? I am using Karate v1.4.1 & Java 17.

actually this depends on the java code you have written to talk to mongo-db and nothing to do with karate at all. hope someone else has better ideas

"Failed looking up TXT record" is a DNS error.  How does Karate handle DNS?

The same code works when I call it from Java main, but not when I call from Karate. I used similar code to this guide from Mongo. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/quick-start/#query-your-mongodb-cluster-from-your-application. Why would it work from main and not from Karate?

@PeterThomas It looks like Karate is not able to resolve srv record? Using a mongo connection string without +srv works.

sorry I don't know, as far as I know karate does not do any networking stuff directly, it just uses the OS. if there is a difference between "main vs karate" my guess is when you run Karate from your IDE, the IDE has not passed the system env and PATH etc correctly, you may need to do some digging into it !
